# How can i fetch county id from google map in flex application

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps

I am try to use Google map in my flex web application with the help of the below link [using Google maps in flex project](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/03/using-google-maps-in-a-flex-project/).

I want to fetch the county id whenever user click on any county of the map.
with the help of the below code i can fetch the latitude and longitude of the county.

```
googleMap.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);



private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
      googleMap.getLatLngBounds();
   }
```

can any one please tell me how can i fetch county id from latitude or longitude.
is there any other way to fetch county id.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well you will need the county polygon data available to be queried, whether this be from a WMS, REST service, or otherwise. You will just run an intersect with the lat/long with the county polygon layer and get a return value from the intersect given you the county name or id. Do you have a query-able county layer available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the below url we can get county id

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=22.937121390987343,78.89300930982809&sensor=false